# Python "Dice Game"

Tags: python, dice

I want to create a simple game in which two players "roll the dice against each other". Winner is whoever gets one number three times in a row. I tried many different ways but in the end I always struggled with the evaluation.
How can I determine which player got one specific number 3-times in a row? Thanks for your advice!

```
import random

#Initialisieren der Variablen
wurf1_1 = 0
wurf2_1 = 0
gewuerfelt_s1 = []
gewuerfelt_s2 = []
n = 1

while (True):
    #Bestimmen der Augenzahlen des Würfels
    wurf1_1 = random.randint(1,6)
    wurf2_1 = random.randint(1,6)
    print("Spiel " + str(n) + ":\tSpieler 1: " + str(wurf1_1) + "; Spieler 2: " + str(wurf2_1))

    gewuerfelt_s1.append(wurf1_1)
    gewuerfelt_s2.append(wurf2_1)

    wurf1_2 = random.randint(1,6)
    wurf2_2 = random.randint(1,6)
    n += 1

    print("Spiel " + str(n) + ":\tSpieler 1: " + str(wurf1_2) + "; Spieler 2: " + str(wurf2_2))

    if (wurf1_2 == gewuerfelt_s1[0]):
        gewuerfelt_s1.append(wurf1_2)
        wurf1_3 = random.randint(1,6)
        n += 1
        print("Spiel " + str(n) + ":\tSpieler 1: " + str(wurf1_3) + "; Spieler 2: " + str(wurf2_2))
        if wurf1_3 == gewuerfelt_s1[1]:
            print("Spieler 1 hat dreimal hintereinander die Zahl", gewuerfelt_s1[1], "gewürfelt. Sieger!")
            break
        else:
            del gewuerfelt_s1[:]
            continue
    else:
        del gewuerfelt_s1[:]
        continue
```

Comment: please show what you have tried

Comment: This is too generic quation, did you have something to share?

Comment: Have a look now

Comment: How many dice rolls are allowed? If it's a fixed number, maybe start with a list of that many numbers, like [1,2,1,1,1,3] and try to find a way to see if that contains three 1s in a row (if you are after the roll of 1)? If we play until someone gets three ones, you can count the first one, then increment if the next roll is one, or reset to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Don't delete elements from your list. You can check the most recently appended elements of a list by indexing from the end

The last element of a list is:

```
my_list[-1]
```

The second last is:

```
my_list[-2]
```

So for each roll after the second roll, you can check:

```
my_list[-1] == my_list[-2] == my_list[-3]
```

Answer (score 1):

(Can't comment, low rep)

First of all, make a function that will simulate the dice, it should return an integer number between [1,6] and should be generated using easily available (pseudo)random functions.
Once this is done, Declare variables, continous1, continous2, prev1, prev2.
The prev variables would store the prev dice role answer for that player if the current turn is the same as the prev for that player, increasing the continuous count. The first to reach the 3 is your answer. Use a while loop to simulate this.

Here is the code

```
import random

continous1 = 0
continous2 = 0
prev1 = 0
prev2 = 0

while continous1 != 3 and continous2 != 3:
    person1 = random.randint(1,6)
    person2 = random.randint(1,6)
    
    if person1 == prev1:
        continous1 += 1
    else:
        continous1 = 0

    
    if person2 == prev2:
        continous2 += 1
    else:
        continous2 = 0
    
    prev1 = person1
    prev2 = person2

# Note that even if both persons win the game at the same time, the first person will be chosen as the winner
if continous1 == 3:
    print("Person 1 won the game")
else:
    print("Person 2 won the game")
```

Comment: I suspect if `continuous2` doesn't equal 3 it's a draw, but that's not clear from the post, also do we need to reset continuous to 1 if we don't match?

Comment: Yes, good catch @doctorlove, I should have reset the continue if a match does not happen. Updated answer. Thanks.

Comment: A draw is not a valid outcome, the game will be played until there is some winner.

Answer (score 0):

Check this pseudo code

```
PlayGame()
{
    bool gameover = false;
    int turns ;
    player1_values = []
    player2_values = []
    While(!gameover)
    {
        player1_values.Add(getrandon(1,6));
        player2_values.Add(getrandon(1,6));
        
        bool player1_won = Check(player1_values);
        if(!player1_won && player1_values.Count == 3)
            player1_values.Clear();
        
        bool player2_won = Check(player2_values);
        if(!player1_won && player2_values.Count == 3)
            player2_values.Clear();
            
        gameover = player1_won || player2_won;
    }
}

Check(values)
{
    if(values.Count < 3)
        return false;
    
    int num = values[0];
    for(int i = 1;i<3;i++)
    {
        if(values[i] != num)
            return false;
    }           
    return true;
}
```